# What's the name for a dual of an abstract simplicial complex

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

A finite abstract simplicial complex is a pair $D=(S,D)$ where $S$ is a finite set and $D$ is a non-empty subset of the power set of $S$ closed under the subset operation.

What's the name for the following:

> $D=(S,D)$ defined as above except that $D$ is closed under the superset operation?

Crossposted from [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49084/dual-of-an-abstract-simplicial-complex).

Comment: An abstract simplicial mplex?

Comment: is there a reason you want to work with abstract simplicial complexes instead of simplicial sets?

Comment: @Sean Tilson: I'm interested in finite set systems with the property of being closed under the superset operation.

Comment: so there are more of these than abstract simplicial complexes, right?

Comment: Right. I'd like to consider them from the point of view of coloring (since they could be interpreted as hypergraphs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [here](http://www.albany.edu/~lenart/articles/ucpol.ps) for simplicial compleces - down closed set system and, respectively, for the objects I asked about - up closed set system.